# What values in the DMA TI.PERMAP field map to each field?

Tags: arm, data-transfer, cpu

In the BCM2835 [datasheet](http://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf), on page 51, it says that bits 20:16 in a DMA control block's Transfer Information word defines its PERMAP -

> Indicates the peripheral number (1-31) whose ready signal shall be
>   used to control the rate of the transfers, and whose panic signals
>   will be output on the DMA AXI bus. Set to 0 for continuous un-paced
>   transfer.

But nowhere in the datasheet can I find which value corresponds to which peripheral! The peripherals, by the way, are things like the SPI, PWM, and PCM modules. This is a pretty crucial bit of information that's lacking, and I can't seem to find it anywhere.

What is the peripheral numbering on the Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it is documented in that pdf. Page 61 shows the following table that maps peripheral number (PERMAP) to the peripheral:

```
DREQ | Peripheral
0    | This is always on so use this channel if no DREQ is required
1    | DSI
2    | PCM TX
3    | PCM RX
4    | SMI
5    | PWM
6    | SPI TX
7    | SPI RX
8    | BSC/SPI Slave TX
9    | BSC/SPI Slave RX
10   | unused
11   | e.MMC
12   | UART TX
13   | SD Host
14   | UART RX
15   | DSI
16   | SLIMBUS MCTX.
17   | HDMI
18   | SLIMBUS MCRX.
19   | SLIMBUS DC0
20   | SLIMBUS DC1
21   | SLIMBUS DC2
22   | SLIMBUS DC3
23   | SLIMBUS DC4
24   | Scaler FIFO 0 & SMI
25   | Scaler FIFO 1 & SMI
26   | Scaler FIFO 2 & SMI
27   | SLIMBUS DC5
28   | SLIMBUS DC6
29   | SLIMBUS DC7
30   | SLIMBUS DC8
31   | SLIMBUS DC9
```

Comment: I think it's only useful for the PCM and PWM peripherals.  I'm not aware of DMA pacing being used on any other peripherals.  I suppose SPI is a possibility.